# How do you include an Authorization http header with an access token in a square api call?

Tags: google-apps-script, square

I'm trying to write square api data to a google sheet and am working through a 401:

Exception: Request failed for https://connect.squareup.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"errors": [{"code": "UNAUTHORIZED","detail": "Your request did not include an `Authorization` http header with an access token. The header value i... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

```
function authorizeSquareUser()
    {
      var service = getSquareService();
      var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
      var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('square/auth-sidebar');
      template.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
      console.log("Auth URL is %s", authorizationUrl);
      template.service = "Square"
      var page = template.evaluate().setTitle('Authorize Square').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(page);
    }
    function listPayments() { 
    
      var url = "https://connect.squareup.com/v2/payments";
      var headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getSquareService().getAccessToken(),
      'Square-Version': '2022-02-16',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      };
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
      var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
      var text = response.getResponseCode();
      Logger.log(data);
      
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script, I think that the request header is not correct. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
```

#### To:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers});
```

or

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getSquareService().getAccessToken(),
    'Square-Version': '2022-02-16',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});
```

#### Note:

- If your access token cannot be used, I'm worried that another error occurs. At that time, please check your access token again.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)